# Doctrine max substring

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

I have a table where I want to extract the highest number contained in a substring of a column. e.g.

**code**

ABC-DEF-001

ABC-DEF-002

ABC-DEF-003

and want to extract "3".

In SQL i can write something like this:

```
select COALESCE(MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(code, 9, 3) AS INTEGER)), 0) from tablename
```

I cannot implement it in Doctrine.

That's what I wrote until now, I cannot find a "CAST" method nor a "coalesce" method.

```
$qb
->select($qb->expr()->max($qb->expr()->substring('code', 9, 3)))
->from(Tablename::class, 'tablename');
```

Any idea, other than "getConnection()->executeStatement()"?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you storing multiple codes within the same column?  I'd fix the design problem before investing time into some Doctrine olympics.

Comment: Sorry it's a problem with the representation of the question. Each row has it's code.